# Handling UI state with Flux and React

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux

with MVC (and Angular in particular), when I want change the ui state in response to data change, I can use a Callback or a Promise to handle it in the controller level, like so:

```
API.voteUp(ITEM_ID).then(function () {
  $scope.isOpen = false;
});
```

with Flux, instead we fire an Action, like:

```
ItemActions.voteUp(ITEM_ID)
```

but there is no way to react directly to the action

I do understand the reason behind it, an know that most state should live in the stores, and that a store should listen to VOTE_UP action and change the UI state accordingly. but it feels that it's not going to scale very well if I need to open a Store for every little UI.
I feels that Flux and the View will become coupled very fast.

below are two scenarios to demonstrate the problem.
the goal is to close the Item component in response to action
and do not mess with the state of the other componenets

the code of the demo available here:
https://github.com/asfktz/flux-ui-state-test

(I'm using Alt Flux, but the implementation doesn't really matter)

## Scenario A: handling UI state in response to Action

### 1. open Item A and Item B

[image: A1]

### 2. Vote for Item A

[image: A2]

### 3. 'VOTE_UP' Action is fired.

Item A should close in respond to the Action - not before

(for example, if the action failed it should stay open)
[image: A3]

## Scenario B: Two different, non related components that handles the same action should not interfere with each other.

### 1. open Item A in both lists

[image: B1]

### 2. vote for Item A in list B.

[image: B2]

### 3. Item A of list B fire 'VOTE_UP' Action

votes update on both lists.

only Item A of list B should close
[image: B3]

#### Notes:

[This blog post](http://www.thomasboyt.com/2014/09/15/no-fit-state.html) describe the same problem

Comment: I actual don't see the problem with this. Why not just use a identifier in the payload during the dispatch? Or using separate actions for each vote.
"_but it feels that it's not going to scale very well if I need to open a Store for every little UI_" - Just think of one store handling *all* the data the one view contains of. And then treat the data as immutable! It scales very good because of this.
It can be that I have misunderstood the problem here..?

Comment: to clarify: In scenario B I see your data-model as
    [{
       name: 'Votes list A',
       items: [{
         name: 'Item A',
         votes: { count: 101 },
       },...]
     },
     {
       name: 'Votes list B',
       items: [{
         name: 'Item A',
         votes: { count: 42 },
     }]
Rather than just one list for each data-store

Comment: @Hulvej, I believe using a store that hold all the state of the current view is good solution, but it has drawbacks. a store updates even if the view is not present on the page. that means that if list A and list B was on different routes, when one fire 'VOTE_UP' the second List closed the item too.

Comment: but thats the point. The stores don't know about there subscribers - and they shouldn't. I guess your state of 'close' will be kept in the data-store as well. The different views and the visibility of them is not relevant.

Comment: OK, so, say we have both lists on the same page, like in Scenario B, and we have a store that hold all the state of the page. 
how do you close one Item and not the other?

Comment: What's your programming question? This seems to be more of an opinion and statement as currently written.

Comment: It is a programming question and I am trying my best to explain it.

Comment: You could add a closed/open state in the same data-structure for each vote-list. See it as two sets of data that just happens to be of familiar structure.

Answer (score 1):

> the goal is to close the Item component in response to action and do not mess with the state of the other componenets

Think of stores as bag of states.  If List A and List B are supposed to have a totally independent data, I would do this:

```
render () {
    return (
        <div className="main">
            <div className="votes-block">
                <h2>Votes List A</h2>
                <List items={this.state.itemsA}/>
            </div>
            <div className="votes-block">
                <h2>Votes List B</h2>
                <List items={this.state.itemsB}/>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Basically having to maintain two items `itemsA and itemsB` for your two items.

Comment: it is the same items on propose. like two different areas in the app that allow voting. the question is if both of them fire 'VOTE_UP', how can we distinguish which list to close?

Comment: By the way heads up: on that repo you forgot to commit the alt export `alt.jsx`.  To answer this question, if they are same items then they represent the same data correct?  If so it doesn't make sense one updates and one won't.  Same if it was a ProfileStore, where it contains your firstName and lastName.  If there are two places that displays this you want those updated.

Comment: In a gist, basically you need one source of truth when it comes to data at least that's how Flux describes it.  If two components rely on that source of truth then they should both update.